# What happen to old Foursquare venue after 2 venues merged?

Tags: foursquare

I am building an app that rely on Foursquare venue, I have a table that associate with the venue id. But the problem is, what will happen if 2 venues merged? Will one of the old venue destroyed, or both destroyed and replace with new id?

Will the old id still able to associate to the newly merged venue?

This is crucial, as it might break my app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The more established venue (generally by number of check-ins) will consume the duplicate venue ID. Requests to the api with the ID of the consumed venue will return the new venue object (with the winning venue ID)